# Error:Abnormal build process termination, while compiling kotlin file in IntelIj

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

Trying to compile kotlin file in Intelij and getting the following error with long trace:

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
/home/stayal0ne/Desktop/kotlin-env/jdk-8u171-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=/home/stayal0ne/trash/KotlinTelegramBot -Dpreload.config.path=/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/config/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-2445885864882950180 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2018.1 -Didea.home.path=/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea -Didea.config.path=/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/config -Didea.plugins.path=/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/config/plugins -Djps.log.dir=/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/system/log/build-log -Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/jre64 -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_152-release -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/system/compile-server/kotlintelegrambot_48229f77/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/tmp/kotlin-idea-6368009607740488460-is-running\" -classpath /home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Desktop/kotlin-env/jdk-8u171-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt/jdk1.8.0_171/lib/tools.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher /home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/platform-api.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/annotations.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/guava-21.0.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/netty-all-4.1.13.Final.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/jna.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/log4j.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/jps-builders.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/asm-all.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/aether-1.1.0-all.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/util.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/javac2.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/resources_en.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/trove4j.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/jps-model.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/httpcore-4.4.5.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/jna-platform.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9-all.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/lz4-java-1.3.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/forms_rt.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/jdom.jar::/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-4.4.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-impldep-4.4.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/gson-2.8.2.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/gson-2.8.2.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/guava-21.0.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/android-base-common.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-4.4.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/gson-2.8.2.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/lib/guava-21.0.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/android-base-common.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-4.4.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/maven/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/osmorc/lib/osmorc-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/osmorc/lib/bndlib-3.3.0.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/osmorc/lib/bnd-repository-3.3.0.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/osmorc/lib/bnd-resolve-3.3.0.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/osmorc/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/osmorc/lib/bundlor-all.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/aspectj/lib/aspectj-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/flex/lib/flex-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/flex/lib/flex-shared.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/jpa-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/webSphereIntegration/lib/jps/webSphere-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/weblogic-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/dmServer/lib/dmServer-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/GwtStudio/lib/gwt-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/google-app-engine-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/appEngine-runtime.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-compiler-patch.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/repository.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/sdklib.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/android-base-common.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger.jar:/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/android-extensions-ide.jar:/home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/config/plugins/Kotlin/lib/android-extensions-compiler.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar:/home/stayal0ne/Downloads/idea/idea/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 41993 1e0f5647-4e35-4812-b8b7-bd7025d7eae3 /home/stayal0ne/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/system/compile-server
/home/stayal0ne/Desktop/kotlin-env/jdk-8u171-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java: 6: /home/stayal0ne/Desktop/kotlin-env/jdk-8u171-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Tried to use various jdk versions and all of them show the same error.

Main.kt:

```
import org.telegram.*
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot
import java.util.*


fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

and build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'

    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "java-library"
apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "java"

apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'main.Main'

repositories {
//    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.7.Final'
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.telegram:telegrambots:3.6"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

I'm building the project using gradle 4.8 and java version "1.8.0_171".
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried building your proj with `./gradlew build`

Comment: @ice1000 , yes, shows the same result

Comment: Retry after `pkill java`? (this may kill your Android Studio as well but will kill all other possible problem-causing gradle daemons

Comment: Is your device using architecture "ARM64"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /home/stayal0ne/Desktop/kotlin-env/jdk-8u171-linux-**arm64**-vfp-hflt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java

You are using an `arm64` JDK, which may not be your current hardware platform. You should reinstall JDK with platform `x86_64` or other which fits your hardware.

Also, it seems you are using Linux, then you may use *package manager* to install the correct version of JDK and JRE automatically, like `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`. (It doesn't matter to use OracleJDK or OpenJDK)

Comment: Geno taiqiangle